# Using CodeIgniter to get dropdown list data but Jquery returning undefined selected values on submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I am trying to serialize the form data and send it to the server using serializeJSON(). However, I am getting empty location array of a dropdown list by which the dropdown list data are retrieved from php using Codeigniter. Even though I have tried to console the selected value I am still getting undefined.

This is how I create dynamic location select option input and I am adding dynamic index on top of that.

```
    $('.location-list').each(function(index){
        $(this).attr("name", "sessions["+ index + "][location]");
    });
```

This is how I show on view retrieving the data from php using CodeIgniter.

```
     <div class="form-group">
        <label>Location</label><br>
        <select class="form-control location-list" required)"
            <!--optgroup?-->
            <option value="" selected disabled>Please select</option>
             <?php       
                 foreach($locations as $row){
                     echo '<option value="'.$row['name'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
                 }
             ?>
        </select>
    </div>
```

This is how I call AJAX and pass serialized data to php.

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: SITE_URL + '/create',
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    event : $('#eventForm').serializeJSON()
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#eventForm')[0].reset();
                    window.location.href = SITE_URL + "pending";        
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrow){
                }
            });
```

Comment: This isn't valid `<select class="form-control location-list" required)"` and if that isn't the problem please a `print_r($_POST);` in the controller `create` and provide the array here

Comment: @Alex I am getting Array
(
    [subject] => abc
    [sessions] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [startdate] => 2018-08-03
                    [starttime] => 12:00
                    [enddate] => 2018-08-03
                    [endtime] => 13:00
                )

        )

)

Comment: there isn't any location value being sent to php

Comment: but you just posted a print_r with values being received from post?

Comment: @Alex yes I am getting some values but the location value from drop down list is missing.

Comment: i'm confused... why are you showing your submit ajax function and talking about how you submit your data if your issue is with the view? show your controller/model code instead. and provide a `print_r($locations)`;

Comment: Here is my controller that I am getting location data from db https://imgur.com/a/WDjSoCq and this is the view https://imgur.com/KcsnUXX that I am able to get the data from php showing on the view.

Comment: ok so if a) you are getting the values when you submit and b) you are "able to get the data from php on the view" then where is your issue: "I am getting empty location array of a dropdown list"????

Comment: I am just showing partial form as you can see here, the location field. I am able to console.log and get all values from the view except selected location value (the one what I print_r) when I submit the form.